# How to specify tls version 'TLSv1.2' when connecting to MySQL using Python peewee

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, tls1.2, peewee, mysql-connector-python

How do I connect to a MySQL database using Python's peewee library while specifying the tls-versions ['TLSv1.1', 'TLSv1.2'] as shown [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-python/en/news-8-0-18.html) and [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encrypted-connection-protocols-ciphers.html) in the MySQL documentation?

I can successfully connect to the MySQL database using mysql.connector as shown here:

```
import mysql.connector

config = {'database': 'dbname',
 'user': 'username_so',
 'password': 'psswrd',
 'host': 'maria####-##-###-##.###.####.com',
 'port': 3306,
 'tls_versions': ['TLSv1.1', 'TLSv1.2']}

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config)

cnx.close()
```

However, I am unable to pass the 'tls_versions' parameter to peewee when establishing a connection. As a result, I get an error message:

> ImproperlyConfigured: MySQL driver not installed!

I am pretty sure that the problem is with specifying the tls versions in peewee because I was getting the same error message with mysql.connector before I added in the additional 'tls_versions' parameter.

Here is the code I am using in peewee that is failing:

```
db = MySQLDatabase(**config)
db.get_tables() # This function and any other that connects to the db gets the same error message specified above
```

My Setup:

```
Linux
Python 3.7
peewee==3.13.3
mysql-connector-python==8.0.21
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I responded to your github issue:

You need to use `playhouse.mysql_ext.MySQLConnectorDatabase` to connect using the mysql-connector driver. That will resolve your issue.